# Strange type error when no match is found

Tags: xslt-3.0

(saxon PE-11.4 xslt 3.0)

sadly I can give an example that fails, because it fails in a 1000 line XSLT, and when i try to create a minimal example it doesnt fail

The error is this

```
The required item type of the value of variable $mediaElement is element(Q{}Media); 
the supplied value text{} does not match. The supplied value is a text node
```

The error is triggered by this code

```
  <xsl:variable name="mediaElement" as="element(Media)*">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="makeMedia" select=".">
        <xsl:with-param name="timeAllocType" select="$timeAllocType"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="product" select="$product"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:variable>
```

and the apply template (I believe) doesnt match anything, so I'm expecting a sequence of 0 Media elements, but for some reason it thinks the result is text().

(I expect its to do with the default rules?)

---

I can prevent the error by suppressing the default text node rule.
(I am really an xslt 1.0 programmer trying to learn xslt 3.0)

so if i add

<xsl:template mode="makeMedia" match="text()"/>

it now works.

But

a) this seems to be painful, I don't want to have to explicitly match text everytime i want to ensure empty matches are empty
b) I can use

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

though what are the ramifications of that?
c) or preserve space, though i cant think what element i'd want to have space.

Comment: The `select="."` selects the context item or node. What is that, really an empty sequence. What is the `xsl:mode` declaration for the mode named `makeMedia`?

Comment: the context item is not an empty sequence pretty much by definition(?). In this case its an element, and the apply template matches no templates, so the value returned is ()? and its type is consistent with element(Media)?

Comment: ive changed the question

Comment: The built- in templates copy text through and recursively process children so I guess you want `<xsl:mode name="makeMedia" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>`

Comment: for me this is quite a common thing, i almost always dont want text nodes turning up in an empty typed sequence, so i assume <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> is the way to go for me?

Comment: `xsl:strip-space` will strip white space text nodes so if you only have empty elements and no text content and then unwanted "text content result" of the apply-templates just consists of such white space text nodes then that will suffice. But if you want to ensure that mode doesn't produce any output unless explicitly matching some of your templates then I still think the suggested `<xsl:mode name="makeMedia" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>`, with XSLT 3, is what you want.

Comment: hmmmm...ok....I understand you, i just havent decided if using strip-space (in my context) is ever a bad idea as the default setting.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I've posted an answer 50% of which is at least down to your comments, feel free to post your own, my interpretation may well be naive/iignorant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that the default xslt templates will match 'text()' and that will be returned when no match is found, and so the type isnt an empty sequence of Media elements, but a sequence of 1 text() node, which is a type error.

The fixes are:
a) <xsl:mode name="makeMedia" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
(as suggested by Martin Honnen in comments)
this will ensure that when no match is made the text nodes are skipped
b) <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
this will strip all space (and thus text nodes) so no text nodes are returned

(there are other variations but this pretty much covers it)

strip-space is the sledgehammer approach as it applies everywhere.
xsl:mode is a forensic approach that will only apply to that specific template mode.

for the moment strip-space works for me.